# React Frontend Issue - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express

I've recently started my path to Full-stack development, though I'm facing the error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

when trying to start the frontend of my app made in React JS with the backend in Node/Express JS, I don't see any error in my code. Can you help me resolve this error?

[image]

No answer on Stack Overflow has helped me resolve the error.

I would appreciate your consideration. Thanks.

Since, I'm not sure where could there be the bug, I can't paste all the code here, so I'm posting a screenshot representing all the four files.

I think there's something messed up in the frontend in App.js file, though I'm unable to identify it so any help will be appreciated.

There are four code windows in the image I posted. Both of the first two windows represent the frontend of the website where App.js file contains the React JS code and the second one is the React package.json file.

The other two belongs to the Node/Express JS backend where the first one contains the Express JS (backend) code and the window next to it is the package.json file of backend directory.

Comment: As one of your first step into fullstack development, let me give you one advice: ReactJS is not a framework and thus your app is not made in ReactJS. It uses ReactJS as the UI library.

Comment: without seeing the actual error, it sounds like your `fetch` call (specifically the call to `res.json()`) is failing because your response contains html instead of json. I'd try reading your response as text to see what it actually contains

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Everything does look ok. You've got the front-end proxy set up correctly to forward requests to your Express API. The only thing I can think of is that you haven't restarted the dev server since adding `proxy` to your `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the port of the backend:

Replace

```js
fetch("api")
```

with

```js
fetch("http://localhost:5000/api")
```

Comment: No. I have clearly mentioned the use of "proxy": "http://localhost:5000" in my package.json file in my react app. Also, the error went away after restarting the react app.

Comment: then it means you haven't saved after changing the proxy... so there is no error here except the fact that you didn't press Ctrl + S.

Comment: What makes you think I'm so dumb that I didn't save the changes after doing them?

Comment: @SharjeelFaiq i didn't say you're dumb. Being careless happened to the best of us. The problem is there's nothing wrong with your code, and the error went away after restarting which means the only way of producing the error is that you forgot saving.